# Set identity on the column identity to another table's column in SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, identity-column

I have a table `TABLEA` with `ID` as an `IDENTITY` column. The last record inserted in table `TABLEA` carries (say 1000 as that identity column value).

I am creating a `#temp` table with `ID` as an `identity` column. I need to set the seed for this identity to continue from `TABLEA`'s `ID` last entered identity value (in this case 1001).

I don't want to set that based on `max(ID)` of `TABLEA`. Please suggest any other alternative option.

Thanks in advance.

Note: I am using SQL Server 2005.

`DBCC RESEED` will not be possible as it requires admin permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Temp Table SET IDENTITY INSERT ON for First Insert do the first INSERT then SET IDENTITY INSERT OFF then other Insert and your seed will start from there on something like this ..

```
CREATE TABLE #Temp (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), Column1 CHAR(1));
GO

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Temp ON;

INSERT INTO #Temp (ID, Column1)
VALUES (1000, 'A');

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #Temp OFF;

INSERT INTO #Temp ( Column1)
VALUES ( 'B');

SELECT * FROM #Temp
```

**Result Set**

```
ID     Column1
1000    A
1001    B
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ROW_NUMBER()` to generate the values for `#Temp` table:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.TableA ...

DECLARE @LastID INT;
SET @LastID = SCOPE_IDENTITTY();

CREATE TABLE #Temp 
(
    Col1 INT PRIMARY KEY, 
    Col2 VARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT #Temp ...
SELECT @LastID + ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY @@SPID), ...
FROM ...
```